# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null

Tags: javascript

I try this code to check val in array2 is square in val array1, my code it works but i get error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null'

```
let comp = (array1, array2) => {
  var index;
  if (array1.length === null && array2.length === null) return false;
  array2.forEach( (val) => {
    if (array1.includes(Math.sqrt(val))) {
      index = array1.indexOf(Math.sqrt(val));
      array1.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
  return array1.length == 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: `if (array1.length === null && array2.length === null)`doesn't really make sense. In what case would you expect the `length` property to be `null`?

Comment: `my code it works but i get error` how does it work then?

Comment: `if (array1.length === null && array2.length === null) return false;` this should be re written to `if (!array1  || !array2) return false;` This will check all truthy case of array1  and array2

Comment: You can check if something is an array by doing `Array.isArray(myArray)` and then proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

I guess instead of checking `array2.length === null` you should try `array2.length === 0`

Comment: Wrong `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null` which means `array2` is null. This will also fail for `array2.map`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line at the top of the function:

```
let comp = (array1, array2) => {
    var index;
    if (array1 == null && array2 == null) return false;
    // Rest of the function
}
```